# using string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

please help me in my site. 
I try to use autocomplete filed jquery, and value take from string javascript variable. 
Why there is using like one string, and not like array?

```
var my_string = "\"ololo1\", \"ololo2\""
var availableTags = [ my_string ];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
});
```

have this one :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH1OY.png

but if i set static variable, its ok, explain me please :

```
var availableTags = [ "ololo", "ololo2" ];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
});
```

result :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVT90.png

Thanks

Comment: `[ my_string ]` does not convert it to array with two elements, only with one single element - full initial string, but `var availableTags = my_string.split(',');` does.

Comment: Because the jQuery autocompleter expects an array of strings as the source and not a single string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,

```
var my_string = "\"ololo1\", \"ololo2\""
var availableTags = [ my_string ];
```

`availableTags` is an array of one element `"ololo1", "ololo2"`. It is not an array of the elements `"ololo1"` and `"ololo2"`, that you might have thought.

To use `my_string` as a source, split it to transform it into an array of tags. I'd also remove the double quotes.

```
var my_string = "ololo1,ololo2";
var availableTags = my_string.split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a string as the source, the Autocomplete plugin expects the string to point to a URL that will return JSON data (http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source). It's best to use an array for the source like you have in your second code snippet.